# Cannot get WCF Data Services samples to run

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, wcf-data-services

Running Windows 7 Enterprise. VS2013 installed.

I am unable to run any WCF Data Services applications. (e.g. http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/WCF-Data-50-for-OData-v3-53074189)

I receive the following exception:

```
Configuration endpoint extension 'standardEndpoints/webHttpEndpoint' could not be found. Verify that this endpoint extension is properly registered in system.serviceModel/extensions/endpointExtensions and that it is spelled correctly.
```

I had a coworker try and they were able to run the sample immediately with no exception.

I feel like this means some sort of WCF component is missing, but Google is of no help on this one.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.. the problem was that I was somehow missing the extension definition for webHttpEndPoint in my machine.config.

e.g.

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <extensions>            
        <endpointExtensions>                
            <add name="webHttpEndpoint" type="System.ServiceModel.Configuration.WebHttpEndpointCollectionElement, System.ServiceModel.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />                
        </endpointExtensions> 
    </extensions>
  <system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Glad to hear you figured it out!

Answer (score 1):

From [MSDN - Deploying an Internet Information Services-Hosted WCF Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751792(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Ensure That IIS, ASP.NET and WCF Are Correctly Installed and
>   Registered
>
> ---
>
> WCF, IIS, and ASP.NET must be installed for IIS-hosted WCF services to
>   function correctly. The procedures for installing WCF (as part of the
>   WinFX), ASP.NET and IIS vary depending on the operating system version
>   being used. For more information about installing WCF and the WinFX,
>   see Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Web Installer. Instructions for
>   installing IIS can be found at Installing IIS.
>
> The installation process for the WinFX automatically registers WCF
>   with IIS if IIS is already present on the machine. If IIS is installed
>   after the WinFX, an additional step is required to register WCF with
>   IIS and ASP.NET. You can do this as follows, depending on your
>   operating system:
>
> • Windows XP SP2, Windows 7, and Windows Server
>   2003: Use the ServiceModel Registration Tool (ServiceModelReg.exe)
>   tool to register WCF with IIS: To use this tool, type
>   ServiceModelReg.exe /i /x in the Visual Studio command prompt. You can
>   open this command prompt by clicking the start button, selecting All
>   Programs, Microsoft Visual Studio 2012, Visual Studio Tools, and
>   Visual Studio Command Prompt
>
> • Windows Vista: Install the Windows Communication Foundation
>   Activation Components subcomponent of the WinFX. To do this, in
>   Control Panel, click Add or Remove Programs and then Add/Remove
>   Windows Components. This activates the Windows Component Wizard.
>
> • Windows 7:
>
> Finally you must verify that ASP.NET is configured to use the .NET
>   Framework version 4. You do this by running the ASPNET_Regiis tool
>   with the –i option. For more information, see ASP.NET IIS Registration
>   Tool

I've seen this issue before with configuring WCF services to run on newly stood up servers and dev/staging environments that I've stood up from scratch. The information on this link has assisted multiple times with this.

Comment: Following this link has unfortunately made no difference. Still get the same error.